# Bootstrap Checkbox to Radio Button Group Conversion Boolean

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, radio-button, boolean

I have been reading through many tutorials and postings about how to use the bootstrap radio button group in replacement to standard check boxes. Unfortunately, none I found were really geared towards my situation.

When a user is created, I can choose if need to be upgraded to an "admin" or "moderator". By default, all users are "basic users" unless the check box is clicked upgrading the user to either a "moderator" or "admin".

I want to convert these to a toggle, since at this time, both a "moderator" and "admin" can be checked, which obviously causes errors.

**Form Element**

```
 <div class="controls">
   <%= f.check_box :admin %>Administrator
   <%= f.check_box :moderator %>Moderator
 </div>
```

**HTML Output:**

```
<div class="controls">
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="user[admin]">
    <input id="user_admin" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[admin]">
        Administrator
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="user[moderator]">
     <input id="user_moderator" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[moderator]">
        Moderator
</div>
```

I am looking at the bootstrap doc for the basic setup:

```
 <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="1" name="user[admin]" id="user_admin">Administrator</button>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="1" name="user[moderator]" id="user_moderator">Moderator</button>
</div>
```

Both items are setup as "boolean" in the database.

How do I go about getting rails to register if one of the buttons was clicked?

I am pretty sure this is going to need a javascript call out

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tried using radio buttons so the user can be upgraded to either be and admin OR moderator.

```
<form >
<p><input name="group1" id="r1" type="radio"  /><label for="r1">admin</label></p>
<p><input name="group1" id="r2" type="radio"  /><label for="r2">moderator</label></p>
</form>
```

Comment: I am trying to keep the style uniform implementing the bootstrap layout. If I convert to simple radio buttons, then I loose what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry i missed the whole twitter part, not familiar with it. Is it possible to supersede moderator with admin... if both are clicked the role is admin.

Comment: I was able to figure it out using a source I found while searching the web. I will post link if I can re-locate it

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out using these the below configuration.

**JS**

```
  $('.radio-style input:checkbox').click(function() {
$(this).siblings('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
 });
```

**Output**

```
  <div class="radio-style">
    <%= f.check_box :admin %><%= f.label :admin %>
    <%= f.check_box :moderator %><%= f.label :moderator %>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .radio-style input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

  .radio-style input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

 .radio-style input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
       background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        background-color:#e0e0e0;
}
```